# how to root and use google play service

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-project-tango, android-rom

i am using project tango development kit( Tablet model NX-74751) and the lenovo phab2 pro(smartphone model Lenovo PB2-690N) to develop project tango.

problem 1:
how to root the tablet of project tango development kit( Tablet model NX-74751)

problem 2:
how to use google play service on lenovo phab2 pro(smartphone model Lenovo PB2-690N). Because I am inside China GreatFireWall, the rom in my phab2pro does not include Google Play Service.
so, i need the international rom for phab2pro and the instructure how to flash the new rom,
Or, any patch to install GoogleService on the Chinese edition of  the phab2pro, thanks

problem3:
how to root the lenovo phab2 pro(smartphone model Lenovo PB2-690N) .

Answer (score 0):

best way to root the tablet is via the root package for yellowstone by chainfire. google "cf-auto-root for yellowstone tablet"    i have nothing to suggest for your other 2 questions.